# I broke the GND (I think) pin of my devices micro USB port. How to fix it?

Tags: usb, port

While putting force to plug usb cable to the port I broke the GND pin of the microUSB port. The port is probably soldered to the device's PCB, and the device itself is not disassemble friendly (Sphero R2D2 toy).

**What are my options to charge the device?**
Can I modify a USB cable to support charging this particular port for example?

[[image: Right most tooth broken from the tongue]Right most tooth broken from the tongue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yun1.jpg)

I think I broke pin 5:

[image: I think I broke pin 5]

Comment: This isn't something you fix unless you are willing to do soldering work.  I would not use this port at all, due to the damage, all pins are important.

Comment: I'm willing to solder. But my problem is can't access the PCB (unbox the case).  Can I just solder the gnd pin in this state ?

Comment: No; You will need to purchase a new port, remove the current part, and replace it entirely.  You risk further damage repairing it any other way

Comment: @Codevalley: I recommend to use the keyword "disassembly" in a web search with your toy's name -- it often helped me to find some nice guides how to open a thing w/o damaging. In your case [this page](https://www.microcontrollertips.com/teardown-inside-spheros-r2-d2-toy/) looks promising.

Comment: @Codevalley: However, soldering the new USB port should be easy, for _unsoldering_ the old one from a multilayer PCB you'll need some practice. I at least recommend to watch some video tutorials...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will try it out. The challenge is open the casing without breaking plastic. Also finding a usb port replacement that fits the space, but pretty sad that the port broke off in the 4th charging attempt (the r2d2 is 0 days old)

Answer (score 2):

The USB port looks to be in bad shape, so I would counsel the replacement of the
whole thing.

I suggest asking for advice from
[Sphero Support](https://support.sphero.com/category/0jfj8702ah-r-2-d-2)
about how to open the case.
If they don't answer, maybe a computer repairman can help with this unusual case,
to open the case without breaking it.